# Is checking for $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] Foolproof?

Tags: ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] <> 'XMLHttpRequest')) 
    {
    exit; 
    }

Is there any method to simulate an Ajax request, that can still make it through, past this check?

If yes, is there any way to avoid it? From the dozen or so articles that I found on this, I see this is pretty much foolproof, but I wanted to make sure!

EDIT 1 : Tried to bypass it with telnet, it successfully managed to stop that! This is what I tried :

`telnet www.example.com 80`

Followed by:

```
GET /functions/protectedpage?id=1 HTTP/1.1
host: www.example.com
```

Comment: no. pretty much ALL of the http headers are trivially spoofable/forgeable by the user and/or intermediate network gear. You cannot trust anything in any of the headers.

Comment: Could you point me at the resources for one of these methods? If I cannot stop it, atleast I would like to learn all that I can about it!

Comment: telnet to your server's port 80. enter an http request sequence. boom. now you can enter any header you want.

Comment: Just tried that, this check seems to work! Got directed to a blank page. Added telnet code that I tried, to the original post. Can you tell me if that is what you meant?